# In Play, when rendering JSON can I use anonymous types and/or object initializers?

Tags: json, playframework

I'm writing a Play application that will have dozens of controller actions that return JSON. The format of each JSON result is slightly different, built up from a few primitives.

I would like to avoid creating a Java class to hold the return type for each action method, so currently I am using a HashMap, like this:

```
// used to populate the filters for an iphone app
public static void filters()
{
    // get four lists from the database
    List<Chef> chefs= Chef.find("order by name asc").fetch();
    List<Cuisine> cuisines = Cuisine.find("order by name asc").fetch(); 
    List<Meal> meals  = Meal.find("order by name asc").fetch(); 
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = Ingredient.find("order by name asc").fetch(); 
    // return them as JSON map
    Map<String,Object> json = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    json.put("chefs", chefs);
    json.put("cuisines", cuisines);
    json.put("meals", meals);
    json.put("ingredients", ingredients);
    renderJSON(json);
}
```

This returns JSON that looks like this, which is what I want:

```
{ 
  "chefs": [{},{},...{}],
  "cuisines": [{},{},...{}],
  "meals": [{},{},...{}],
  "ingredients": [{},{},...{}]
}
```

I feel like **the syntax to construct the HashMap is redundant**. I don't have a ton of Java experience, so I'm comparing to C# which lets me use an *anonymous type* with an *object initializer*, to cut down on the code like so:

```
return Json(new
{
    chefs = chefs,
    cuisines = cuisines,
    meals = meals,
    ingredients = ingredients
});
```

**Is there anything in the Java/Play world that let's me write this kind of code more compactly?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact equivalent to the C# construct in Java, however you can create an anonymous object and initialize it using the idiom illustrated below:

```
public static void filters()
{
  renderJSON(new HashMap<String,Object>(){{

    // get four lists from the database
    List<Chef> chefs= Chef.find("order by name asc").fetch();
    List<Cuisine> cuisines = Cuisine.find("order by name asc").fetch(); 
    List<Meal> meals  = Meal.find("order by name asc").fetch(); 
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = Ingredient.find("order by name asc").fetch(); 

    // return them as JSON map
    put("chefs", chefs);
    put("cuisines", cuisines);
    put("meals", meals);
    put("ingredients", ingredients);

  }});
}
```

(You could put the four lists declarations outside the anonymous type initializer, but then you would need to declare them final.)

Comment: Unfortunately, that just returns an empty string.   renderJSON(new HashMap<String,Object>(){{
  put("foo", "string");
  put("bar", 123);
}});

Comment: Interesting.  It seems the reflection magic in renderJSON does not handle subclasses of maps.  Creating an actual HashMap from the anonymous map does work:  Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>(){{ put("foo", "string"); put("bar", 123); }}; renderJSON(new HashMap<String,Object>(map));

Comment: I did some another test, and renderJSON does handle normal subclasses of HashMap.  So it is only anonymous subclasses that cause problems.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem.  Play Framework uses the GSON library which does not handle anonymous classes, as explained in http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=298 (see Comment 2)

Answer (score 0):

Java does have anonymous types, which you should be able to use just fine:

```
// these would be accessed from DB or such; must be final so anonymous inner class can access
final String _name = "Bob";
final int _iq = 125;
renderJSON(new Object() {
  public String name = nameValue; // or define 'getName()'
  public int iq = iqValue; // ditto here
});
```

this creates anonymous inner class, and then JSON data binder should be able introspect it, serialize stuff and so on.

Comment: The Play framework doesn't seem to like the fact that these variables are `final`. I get the following exception: "Class play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer$FieldAccessor can not access a member of class controllers.TestController$1 with modifiers "public""

Comment: Interesting limitation of Play, then -- there should not be any fundamental problem, as JSON frameworks like Jackson would allow such usage.